Is there a way to have Custom legends to toggle lines in Echarts
I am developing a multi chart layout using echarts library.
All the charts have same legends but different dataset.
Is there way to make custom legend sections in echarts using which I can handle all the charts at once ?
I have tried toggling "show" property of each series and also "visible" property but all the do is hide the data points on chart not the complete series.

You can add a shared legend and use it in all of your charts
const legend = {
    type: 'scroll',
    orient: 'vertical',
    right: 10,
    top: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    data: ['Legend A', 'Legend B', 'Legend C' /* ... */, , 'Legend x']
    // ...
  }

// chart 1
const chart1 = echarts.init(dom1)
chart1.setOption({
    legend,
    dataset: {
      source: [
        // ...
      ]
    },
    // other settings...
  },
})

// chart 2
const chart2 = echarts.init(dom2)
chart2.setOption({
    legend,
    dataset: {
      source: [
        // ...
      ]
    },
    // other settings...
  },
})


or you can wrap in your own function
function createEchartOption(dataset){
  return {
    dataset,
    legend: {
    type: 'scroll',
    orient: 'vertical',
    right: 10,
    top: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    data: ['Legend A', 'Legend B', 'Legend C' /* ... */, , 'Legend x']
    // ...
  },
  // other settings...
}

const chart = echarts.init(dom)
chart.setOption(createEchartOption({...}))



Would it be possible to provide a working example for the same ?

I'm really sorry, but I'm quite tied up at the moment. How about you provide an example of your current solution and I adjust it for you.

Sorry for replying this late @Hao. The answer you provided worked like a charm.
